# Calling ActionResult from controller differs than Calling it from View, I need them the same

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a Controller which handles the Payment process, when I call it from the View like the below:

```
<input type="button" value="Create" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Pay", "Payment")'" />
```

It works fine, and it redirects me to PayPal Gateway .

But it doesn't work when I call the same method on a certain event from another controller like the below :

```
 PaymentController payment = new PaymentController();
 payment.PaymentWithPaypal(obj.Amount);
```

Here's a piece of code from the Payment Controller :

```
    [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PaymentWithPaypal(string amount)
    {

        //getting the apiContext  
       APIContext apiContext = PaypalConfiguration.GetAPIContext();
        try
        {

            string payerId = Request.Params["PayerID"];
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(payerId))
            {...}
        }
     }
```

I got this error :

> {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."} System.Exception {System.NullReferenceException}

it seems that the "Request" is null, and it has not HttpContext !

Okay what I need is to simulate the exact behavior of calling an ActionResult from a view .

Many Thanks,

Comment: You should not call the controller from another controller. Instead, make a business logic component that handles payments and call that from both controllers.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the technical problems, what would you expect to happen? You cannot redirect to a different page *in the middle of a controller call*.

If you want to redirect to the action as the end of your controller call, use `RedirectToAction`:

```
return RedirectToAction("PaymentController", "PaymentWithPaypal", new { PayerID = playerId, Amount = "$1.234" });
```

You *could* also call the controller method directly, if you made sure that you don't touch all the behind the scenes http logic. Why is `PayerID` not a method parameter? If you make it a method parameter, it would be much easier to write automated tests, too.